# upload image to content in Yii

Tags: yii

I have 2 tables, postimage and post. Postimage has fields post_id, id and image. I need to create upload form of the image and show it when content created. This image should be lincked to the content(though post_id field). Uploading form appears but images don't uploading. I tried such a way:

```
class PostImageController extends Controller
{

    public $layout='//layouts/column2';

    /**
     * @return array action filters
     */
    public function filters()
    {
        return array(
            'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
            'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        );
    }

    /**
     * Specifies the access control rules.
     * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
     * @return array access control rules
     */
    public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a particular model.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $this->render('view',array(
            'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new PostImage;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['PostImage']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['PostImage'];
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
                $path=Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/'.$model->image->getName();
                $model->image->saveAs($path);
                //$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Updates a particular model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['PostImage']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['PostImage'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Deletes a particular model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }

    /**
     * Lists all models.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('PostImage');
        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Manages all models.
     */
    public function actionAdmin()
    {
        $model=new PostImage('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['PostImage']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['PostImage'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
     * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
     * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
     * @return PostImage the loaded model
     * @throws CHttpException
     */
    public function loadModel($id)
    {
        $model=PostImage::model()->findByPk($id);
        if($model===null)
            throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Performs the AJAX validation.
     * @param PostImage $model the model to be validated
     */
    protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='post-image-form')
        {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }
    }
}
```

PostImage model:

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "PostImage".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'PostImage':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $image
 * @property integer $post_id
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Post $post
 */
class PostImage extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public $image;
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'PostImage';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            //array('image', 'required'),
            array('post_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('image', 'length', 'max'=>255),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, image, post_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'post' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Post', 'post_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'image' => 'Image',
            'post_id' => 'Post',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     *
     * Typical usecase:
     * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
     * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
     * models according to data in model fields.
     * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
     *
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
     * based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('image',$this->image,true);
        $criteria->compare('post_id',$this->post_id);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return PostImage the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

And this is view of the form:

```
<?php 
echo CHtml::form('','post',array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); 
echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image');
echo CHtml::endForm(); 

?>
```

Comment: Share the full code of the view.

Comment: actually this is the code that I used from this receipt  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/            I need to post this form in the view that add content.

Comment: I think that you have two forms and one which is of Image does not sent.